# Bootstrap 4 navbar changes item color when resized

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am having a problem wwith B4 navbar changing its items font color when I am resizing the browser. Unfortunately I cannot replicate it with any example. Here are some images.

Initial look:
[image]

After resizing to I think 768 width:

[image]

As you can see it changes the color to black. Any idea why that is happening?

Thanks

Update.
Adding B4 Media query that does it:

```
/*Bootstrap overrides for toggle button when menu fully collapses*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
       background: white;
    }
    .nav-icon-text {
        color: black;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav> .Active {
        background-color: rgb(0,114,187);
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li:hover {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

My navigation bar is not collapsible and I am not using Hamburger button. Can I stop this behavior?

Comment: .nav-icon-text { color: black; } does the change, so just override it in your css with this @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) { .nav-icon-text: #FFFFFF; }

Answer (score 1):

You have more options. First is to find corresponding css rule in bootstrap CSS somewhere in

```
@media all and (max-width:768px) {
}
```

Better approach is to inspect DOM element by your browser. Click on the navbar li element with the right click and choose inspect element option. Then you can see, what CSS rules are applied to your DOM element, find the one which is changing the color and change, remove, overwrite it.

The worst approach is to set the color for navbar elements with !important flag

For testing responsivity, you don't have to resize your browser window. Just press ctrl+shift+m in firefox or click on mobile device icon in google chrome inspector.

Comment: Great, will do that.